# Connecting an HTML webpage to a SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, html, azure

I am attempting to display a table from my Azure SQL database on a webpage. I have been looking around and can't seem to figure out why this isn't working

This is where I am connecting to the database:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<?php
$host="myname.database.windows.net";
$username="theUser";
$password="password";
$database="databaseName";
$tbl_name="tableName";

$mysql = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($database);
$sql='SELECT * FROM $tbl_name';
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

?>
```

This is where I create a formatted table:

```html
<table id="MySqlTable" align="center" style="width:70%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>LiftId</th>
        <th>ItemNumber</th>
        <th>ItemRegion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

This is where I am trying to fill the rows with the information being pulled from the database:

```html
<? php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <? php echo $row['LiftId']?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <? php echo $row['ItemNumber']?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <? php echo $row['ItemRegion']?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <? php  
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($mysql);
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

This is the final product that I am getting from this code. Why is the information not being displayed in the rows?? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5d3s.png

Comment: try to change `$sql='SELECT * FROM $tbl_name';` to `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";` or `$sql='SELECT * FROM ' . $tbl_name;`

Comment: That didn't change anything. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to turn on some debugging and consider using mysqli as mysql is deprecated.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-php here's a good tutorial

For debugging add

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//and
if (!$mysql) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host="myname.database.windows.net";
$username="theUser";
$password="password";
$database="databaseName";
$tbl_name="tableName";

$mysql = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
if (!$mysql) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database);
$sql='SELECT * FROM $tbl_name';
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

?>
```

Comment: I have already tried debuggers. They don't seem to be displaying anything when I run the code, which makes me think that it should be working? I ran them on $mysql, $sql, and $result

Answer (score 0):

In reading your question, it says connecting an HTML page to a SQL database.  When I read that, it leads me to believe your HTML page has the .html extension.  The PHP code required to make a MySQL connection needs a .php extension to run.

Comment: I thought that putting <? php and ?> around the php sections would make it work. How would I separate the two, because they are very intertwined

Comment: Yes, in a file with .php as the extension.  <?php and ?> are called delimiters and they tell the server on the server side to execute php code inside them.  Otherwise, the server will interpret your php code as HTML thinking you wanted to display code on your .html file.  By the way, do not include a space after the first <? php.  It should be <?php or else it will throw an error.

Comment: I just read the second part of your comment.  I don't think there is a need to separate the two.  HTML will run inside a .php file.  I recommend changing your filename to have the extension .php and see where that takes you.

Comment: How will the php file know to run html in certain sections?

Comment: Anything outside the php delimiters (and not inside other types of delimiters) is HTML in a .php file.  Try this example in a new file called file.php 

<html>html here <?php echo 'php here'; ?> back to html. </html>

Comment: That example is to show you how you can have HTML and PHP side-by-side in a .php file.  If everything on your server is set up to run PHP, you should see "html here php here back to html". when you load file.php.

Comment: I think that I got confused, I am very new to this. We are not using mysql, only sql for the database. does that mean that I can't use php?